Is the torus normalizer for $E_6$ a split extension?
Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field. For the linear group $L_n(q)$ the torus normalizer is a split extension $(q-1)^{n-1}:S_n$. Actually, the full extension does not necessarily split, but the derived subgroup $(q-1)^{n-1}:A_n$ (of index $2$) does. This is also true for the other classical groups $B_n$, $C_n$, and $D_n$, and I'm pretty sure it's also true for the exceptional groups $G_2$ and $F_4$. For $E_6$, however, it seems that the extension $(q-1)^6.U_4(2)$ does not split (it does split in characteristic $2$, so let's focus on odd characteristic). I'm guessing this carries over to infinite fields, but I'm mostly interested in finite fields.
To see why the extension shouldn't split, let's review Dickson's construction of $E_6$:

We define $6$ indices, say $1,2,3,4,5,6$.
We define a $27$-dimensional space with basis vectors $x_i$, $y_j$, and $z_{ij}=-z_{ji}$.
We define a cubic form as the sum of terms $x_iy_jz_{ij}$, and $z_{ij}z_{kl}z_{mn}$, where $(1,2,3,4,5,6)\rightarrow(i,j,k,l,m,n)$ is an even permutation.
$E_6(q)$ (or its triple cover) is the group of all $27\times27$ matrices preserving this cubic form. The outer (diagonal) automorphism multiplies "length" by a cubic root of unity.

Now, the torus normalizer should contain a subgroup $2^6.U_4(2)$, and the question is whether or not this extension splits. The answer seems to be no; let's walk through why.
We will assume there is a $U_4(2)$ complement and obtain a contradiction. Then for each basis vector, the stabilizer is $2^4:A_5$; in particular, it does not have a subgroup of index 2. Hence, this subgroup should always preserve the sign. In fact, an element of $U_4(2)$ should preserve the sign of all basis vectors that it stabilizes. So, all I would need to do from here is to show that some element must flip the sign of a basis vector, but I couldn't quite figure this out. Can someone please confirm (or deny) that $2^6.U_4(2)$ is a nonsplit extension?
